# How to filter a collection based on date and assign it to a map

Tags: go

I have a struct that represents a Purchase:

```
type Purchase struct {
  id int64
  UserId int64
  CreatedAt  time.Time
}
```

Now I have a collection of these purchases.

On the UI side I am doing this:

1. Get the current date, and display the last 2 weeks dates.
2. If a purchase falls within a date, display it.

So it would look like:

```
Sunday May 29th
- date/timestamp purchase id, amount, etc.
- date/timestamp purchase id, amount, etc.
Saturday May 28th
- date/timestamp purchase id, amount, etc.
Friday May 27th
..
..
(past 2 weeks).
```

So my algorithm would be:

1. get the current date
2. using the current date, loop through the previous 2 weeks and search my Products collection and if the CreatedAt is the given date insert it into a collection
3. On the UI side, loop through this collection, where the key is the day

So the current date is:

```
t := time.Now()
```

How can I traverse the past 2 weeks and then insert it into a map.

Is there a better algorithm that you would suggest?

Comment: You can map your purchase by date: map[time.Time][]Purchase, so you do not have to do that on UI side. If your collection is not sorted by time, then you have to traverse it all. If it is sorted by time, then you have to take the first elements until you cross the 2-weeks deadline. Else, you may want to sort it by time. For that, you have to implement the [sort Interface](https://godoc.org/sort#Interface).

Comment: @T.Claverie what about getting the previuos 2 weeks of days, do I need a calender type class or?

Comment: The `time` library should be plenty enough to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

An approach may be to arrange the entries in time-series structures and use that to filter required entries within some interval. We may use a map like map[timestamp_bucket][]Purchase. time-stamp bucket may be calculated as (time_stamp_corresponding_to_purchase_date_in_second - (time_stamp_corresponding_to_purchase_date_in_second % 3600)).  Basically, we arrange the purchases in hourly buckets.  When we want to get last two weeks purchases, we just compute the time_bucket keys that fall in last two weeks and retrieve the purchases from the corresponding buckets in the map. We may keep the slice []Purchase sorted if required if we want to use arbitrary time intervals to filter the records.